# Can we have the well founded world of NF obeying ZF?

Tags: set-theory, lo.logic, new-foundations

The following question is about the possibility of having a world of sets obeying new foundations "**NF**" with their well founded sets obeying rules of **ZF**. It uses the revised version of Quines $``ML"$ ([Mathematical Logic (chapter 4)](https://archive.org/details/QUINEMathematicalLogic/mode/2up)) system, in order to define well foundedness in a faithful manner, and then adds axioms of size and infinity over the well founded sector.

FORMAL EXPOSITION:

Language: First order logic with equality and membership with extra-logical axioms of:

**Extensionality:** $\forall z (z \in x \leftrightarrow z \in y) \to x=y$

**Classes:** if $\phi$ is a formula in which $x$ doesn't occur free, then $(\exists x \forall y (y \in x \leftrightarrow set(y) \land \phi))$

Where: $set(y) \iff \exists z(y \in z)$

Define: $x=V \iff \forall y \ (set(y) \to y \in x)$

Define: $x=\{y \in V| \phi\} \iff \forall y (y \in x \leftrightarrow y \in V \land \phi)$

**Stratification:** if $\phi(y,x_1,..,x_n)$ is a stratified formula in which all quantifiers are bounded by $V$, and all free variables of it are among symbols $``y,x_1,..,x_n"$, then:$$\forall x_1 \in V,...,\forall x_n \in V (\{y\in V| \phi\} \in V)$$

**Size:** $x,y\text{ are well founded} \land |x|=|y| \land x \in V \to y \in V$

Where: $\text{well founded} (x) \iff \\\not \exists d (x \cap d \neq \emptyset \land \forall m \in d \exists n \in d (n \in m))$

**Infinity:** $\omega \in V$

Where $\omega$ is the set of all finite Von Neumann ordinals.

> Question 1: Is this theory consistent relative to consistency of $NF$ and $ZF$?
>
> Question 2: if we weaken Extensionality to weak Extensionality of $NFU$, as to allow Ur-elements. Would that be consistent relative to $NFU$ and $ZFU$?

Comment: $V$ in ML has well defined, it is the SET of all sets. I'll add it

Comment: @NoahSchweber. Yes! I've edited my posting to clarify this issue.

Comment: This is an interesting question - I think it might be worth allowing urelements, though, given that NF is comparatively ill-understood.

Comment: @NoahSchweber, Yes. correct. NFU is more understood than NF.

Comment: @NoahSchweber, the other direction in the definition of $V$ is trivial!

Comment: Derp, not my finest moment!

Comment: Editing a question 10 times is a lot.

Comment: @MattF. is there a limit to the total number of times of editing a question on MathOverflow.